# Route::auth() and namespacing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used `make:auth` to create the login scaffold which works nicely in the base app. However I am creating a package so I have moved the files to their respective places in my package.

I have namespaced the route created by the `make:auth` app to

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'Package\Namespace\HomeController@index');
});
```

When I comment out `Route::auth();` everything seems to work fine. When I keep `Route::auth` I get an error

```
Class Auth\AuthController does not exist
```

I cannot understand what the issue is. I don't know much about the `auth()` helper function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obvious error...

Within `Router.php` the `auth()` function namespaces are in relation to the default `Controllers` namespace.

Removing the `auth()` function and adding all the namespaced routes into the routes file of course did the trick

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: I don't see it as so obvious. Shouldn't Auth be solved by the alias?